# xcodebuild setting parameter equivalent in Xcode GUI build?

Tags: xcode6, xcodebuild, xcode-workspace

I have an Xcode workspace. The workspace has multiple projects. Each project has at least 1 target.

The command `xcodebuild` allows you to add setting parameters on the command line. These settings are passed to all targets.

For example, I can build everything in the workspace by doing this:

```
xcodebuild -scheme KitchenSink build BOB=newhart
```

And the setting `BOB=newhart` will be passed to every project.

**What is the equivalent of this when choosing *Product | Build* from the Xcode menu bar (pressing Command+B)?**

Some points:

- I would prefer not to edit every project.
- I created an xcconfig file named "Global", but how do I get the Xcode build process to use it for all targets?

  - The *Build* section when editing a scheme does not contain a way to attach xcconfig files.
  - When I select Global.xcconfig in the Navigator pane, and look at the File Inspector in the Utilities pane, I do not see a way to add that file to any targets.
  - The xcconfig file is only part of the workspace. It is not part of any 1 project.
  - I'm not certain the use of xcconfig files is how to accomplish what I want; I'm just explaining what I've tried.